# Как можно сделать так, чтобы через определенное время в базе обновлялось поле?

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно сделать так, через определенное время в базе обновлялось поле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужно все время прибегать к крону, есть и более прагматичные способы:
например встроенный планировщик заданий БД( начиная с 5.1)

- [Using the Event Scheduler(офф док)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)
- [Использование событий MySQL на практике](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123391/)

**ОБН**

**Пример** (свои данные выставляйте здесь)

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
EVENT swg.event1
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '3' MINUTE
    STARTS '2013-03-25 18:48:25'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO 
BEGIN
  if(select ваш_столбик from ваша_табличка)<100 then
      update ваша_табличка set ваш_столбик=ваш_столбик+1;
    end if;

END
```

Comment: у меня вообщем такое дело, есть поле fuel по умолчанию 100 я проверяю if($fuel < 100){
то тут написать код который через 3 мин добавить к поле fuel 1 и так доконца пока 100 не будет,
}


напиши код если можно(((

Comment: а он только один раз добавит???

Comment: каждые 3 минуты будеть проверять. Смотрите синтаксис.

Comment: и еще его в php код вставлять? если так то пишет! 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Z:\home\localhost\www\mobrace\main.php on line 34

строка 34      DEFINER = 'root''localhost'

Comment: нет, в базе создаете. только проверьте, есть ли у вас привилегия.

Comment: извените а где именно в базе?? sql Запрос сделать????

Comment: Да, sql запросы. Подозреваю что у вас Денвер, тогда например можно через phpMyadmin создать.
Или в сети можете посмотреть как выполнить запросы к БД.

Answer (score 3):

Если определенное время меньше 25с, то

```
sleep($needed_time);
your_update_field_function();
```

в остальных случаях поможет [cron](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron/)

P.S. старайтесь не дублировать вопросы. Даже если очень срочно, горит, рушится и не заплатят зарплату за полгода: скорее всего, вас просто забанят...

UPD:
Судя по задаче, у вас нецелевое использование базы.
Если вам нужно значение поля через время, занесите определенное значение, занесите скорость изменения, занесите дату занесения.

А все, что вам нужно проверяйте и изменяйте ПО ЗАПРОСУ.

Comment: у меня вообщем такое дело, есть поле fuel по умолчанию 100 я проверяю if($fuel < 100){
то тут написать код который через 3 мин добавить к поле fuel 1 и так доконца пока 100 не будет,
}


помоги если можегшь(((